# tkinter label doesnt update before a sleep

Tags: python, tkinter

In the code below, clicking on BadButton never displays the "New BadButton text", it waits two seconds and then displays 'Third BadButton text'
How do I persuade the script to display both messages.
Using Python 2.7.10

```
import os, sys
import time
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

def GoodButton():
   global labeltext

   time.sleep(2)
   labeltext.set('New GoodButton text')

def BadButton():
   global labeltext

   labeltext.set('New BadButton text')
   time.sleep(2)
   labeltext.set('Third BadButton text')

# GUI construction
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Label Problem")
# set background
back = Tkinter.Frame(master=root, width=375, height=125, bg='white')
back.pack()

B1 = Tkinter.Button(root,text ="Test GoodButton", command =     GoodButton)
B1.pack()
B1.place(height=25, width=100, x = 25, y = 25)   # default x,y = 0,0

B2 = Tkinter.Button(root,text ="Test BadButton", command = BadButton)
B2.pack()
B2.place(height=25, width=100, x = 150, y = 25)

# add a label to show progress
labeltext = Tkinter.StringVar(value = 'Ready')
L1 = Tkinter.Label(root,textvariable = labeltext)
L1.pack()
L1.place(height=25, width=175, x = 150, y = 75)

# MAIN
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `time.sleep()` in a Tkinter application at all, because it completely locks up the GUI.  Use Tkinter's `.after()` method to schedule function calls at a future time, instead.

Comment: Here's some documentation on the universal [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `after()` to do what you want:

```
def updateLabel(txt):
  labeltext.set(txt)

def GoodButton():
  root.after(2000, updateLabel, 'New GoodButton text')

def BadButton():
  updateLabel('New BadButton text')
  root.after(2000, updateLabel, 'Third BadButton text')
```